# React in Production: What must be the size of React in production?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I made a `React` app with `Redux, immutable, webpack`. The size of original bundle was 6.55MB, i used React in production tweaks and bundle size is now reduced to 900KB. I further used `webpack-bundle-size-analyzer` to check what is contributing to the size of `bundle.js`. The result of webpack-bundle-size-analyzer` is that React comes out to be the top contender with 577KB.[image]

#### Q1: Is it normal that size of React in production App is 577KB

#### Q2: How can I further reduce the size of React module?

I want this app to run in mobile as well, so 900KB is quite large.

Comment: Have you set the production NODE_ENV flag?  Read this http://moduscreate.com/optimizing-react-es6-webpack-production-build/

Comment: There is also an alternative light weight react implementation called `preact`.  If optimisation and gzipping still doesn't help you out enough you could consider this option. https://github.com/developit/preact

Comment: Yeah, did NODE_ENV already. @ctrlplusb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it normal that size of React in production App is 577KB

Its depends on your application, we don't know it is small or large.

> How can I further reduce the size of React module?

You can use `gzip` compression. For webpack there is plugin - [`compression-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack/compression-webpack-plugin)

Comment: gzip is a setting to be activated in the webserver.